# Add binding to a (Source).(Property).(Property)

Tags: c#, data-binding

So I need to use WinForms because my app will run on mono.

I have a class called Logic and I have a Property of type Part in that class I have a part number. I would like to update the UI with the part number when Part Changes. All I can seem to do is bind to Part and not Part's property.

```
public class Logic : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Part Part { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeSequence(int fixtureId)
    {            
        Part = new Part() {partNumber = "aetrasdsd"};
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Vitrek_Library.Part));
    }
}

public partial class Main : Form
{

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Program.Logic.Initialize(omronEthernetFINSCom1);
        Program.Logic.DataSubFixtureId.DataChanged += DataSubFixtureID_DataChanged;
        Program.Logic.SequenceDone += Logic_SequenceDone;

        Binding b = new Binding("Text", Program.Logic, nameof(Vitrek_Library.Part) + ".partNumber", true)
        {
            //FormatString = $"Part Number: {0}"
        };

        lblPartNumber.DataBindings.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with setting the binding path to Part.partNumber, was that Part was null at the time of the binding.